# Conditionally replace elements in list1 with elements in list2

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am trying to merge two lists but I am getting an `out-of-range` error:

Example:

```
List1 = [1,2,0,7,0]
List2 = [3,6]

For i in range(len(List1)):
    if List1[i] == 0:
        List1[i] = List2[i]
        print(List1)
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You tell us. What is it supposed to do? What does it do instead?   It's got a syntax error as is. Make sure you cut and paste the exact code that gives you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace every element of `List1` that is zero, with an element of `List2`,

**Code:**

```
List1 = [1, 2, 0, 7, 0]
List2 = [3, 6]

l2 = iter(List2)
List1 = [l if l != 0 else next(l2) for l in List1]

print(List1)
```

**Produces:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 7, 6]
```

**Update from comments:**

If `List2` is possibly not long enough, one way around this is to specify a default value for `next()`:

```
List1 = [1, 2, 0, 7, 0, 0]
List2 = [3, 6]

l2 = iter(List2)
List1 = [l if l != 0 else next(l2, None) for l in List1]

print(List1)
```

**Which produces:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 7, 6, None]
```

Comment: If `List1` has more `0`'s than `len(List2)` you will get a `StopIteration` exception, might want `next(l2, 0)` or `next(l2, None)` to handle that.

Comment: it work thank you, i just add next(l2, None) the the code given by Mr Stephen Rauch

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to replace every instance of `0` from `List1` with a value from `List2` matching the index. The issue however is that for `List1`, `0` is at index 2 (indexes start at 0) but the is no item at index 2 for `List2`, hence the reason you get an `IndexError`

```
# Example
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lst[2]
3
>>> lst[3]
# IndexError: list index out of range
```

That explains what is wrong, now what would you like to do instead and maybe we can help.